# Does BOM (Browser object model) in JavaScript has pre-defined class for it? Because every object is an instance of a class right

Tags: javascript, web, browser, web-development-server

My question is does BOM (Browser object model) has per-defined classes, I am asking this because every object is an instance of a class right.

Comment: Yes, but also no. The BOM is different from browser to browser, it does not have any specifications on how it should be implemented, so every browser implements it slightly differently.